# Shaping on ES20/7606-S

Tags: cisco, qos, wan

I've recently moved from point-to-point WAN to a point-to-multipoint WAN, unfortunately this has really messed up my brain...in regards to shaping. These circuits are aggregated into three physical ports and three separate VLAN's. I am trying to shape before the traffic is dropped by the ISP and am running into a problem.

Here is what I am doing:

```
class-map match-any speed-50-test
  match access-group 120
!
policy-map speed-50-test
 class speed-50-test
 bandwidth 50000
 shape average 50000000
!
access-list 120 remark ** speed 50 test **
access-list 120 permit ip any 10.240.0.0 0.0.255.255
!
interface gig 4/0/1
 service-policy output speed-50-test
```

IOS kicks back saying:

```
Match numbered access-list is not supported for this interface
```

IOS version: ipservicesk9-mz.122-33.SRE8.bin

I've seen some threads saying that advanced ip services will allow this. Is this true? Or is this configuration done improperly?

EDIT:

if I use a subinterface I am able to apply this policy (after defining the class-default).

I guess now I am wondering if this is the proper way to accomplish enforcing CIR on this VLAN.